# Need help to get a file as a whole in a single mail which is of the size 4 mb in oracle PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, clob, varchar2

The below code in a PL/SQL procedure checks for the byte size and if it is above 30000 bytes it iterates the data and 
 **sends mail attachments(txt file through multiple mails) for every 30000 bytes(30 kb).**
 I need to **get a file as a whole in a single mail which is of the size 4 mb** in oracle PL/SQL.

The data type of lv_message_tab is varchar2(32767) . Can i user **CLOB** datatype instead of **Varchar2(32767),**if yes please suggest how.

Thanks a million in advance !!!

```
FOR lv_idx in 1..pv_message.COUNT
      LOOP
         lv_message := lv_message||pv_message(lv_idx)|| lv_cr;

         IF LENGTH(lv_message) >= 30000
         THEN

          lv_message_tab.EXTEND;
          lv_message_tab(lv_message_tab.LAST) := lv_message;
          lv_message := null;

         END IF;

      END LOOP;
--This send the attachment for 30000 characters and above
      IF lv_message_tab.COUNT > 0 
      THEN

           FOR lv_idx in 1..lv_message_tab.COUNT
           LOOP

              UTL_SMTP.HELO(lv_conn, lv_smtp_host);
              UTL_SMTP.MAIL(lv_conn, gc_sender);
              UTL_SMTP.RCPT(lv_conn, lv_to_email_ids);
              UTL_SMTP.RCPT(lv_conn, lv_cc_email_ids);

               UTL_SMTP.DATA(lv_conn,
              'Date: '   || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, gc_dd_month_yyyy_format) || lv_cr ||
              'From: '   || gc_sender || lv_cr ||
              'Subject: '|| lv_subject || lv_cr ||
              'To: '     || lv_to_email_ids || lv_cr ||
              'CC: '     || lv_cc_email_ids || lv_cr ||

              'MIME-Version: 1.0'|| lv_cr ||    -- Use MIME mail standard
              'Content-Type: multipart/mixed;'|| lv_cr ||
              ' boundary="-----SECBOUND"'|| lv_cr ||
                lv_cr ||

              '-------SECBOUND'|| lv_cr ||
              'Content-Type: text/plain;'|| lv_cr ||
              ' name="excel.csv"'|| lv_cr ||
              'Content-Transfer_Encoding: 8bit'|| lv_cr ||
              'Content-Disposition: attachment;'|| lv_cr ||
              ' filename="'||pv_file_name||'"'|| lv_cr ||
              lv_cr ||lv_message_tab(lv_idx)
              || lv_cr ||   -- Content of attachment
              lv_cr ||

               '-------SECBOUND--' );   

          END LOOP;

      END IF;

      --This send the attachment for the rest of the data...for the last few iterations
      IF lv_message IS NOT NULL
      THEN



          UTL_SMTP.HELO(lv_conn, lv_smtp_host);
          UTL_SMTP.MAIL(lv_conn, gc_sender);
          UTL_SMTP.RCPT(lv_conn, lv_to_email_ids);
          UTL_SMTP.RCPT(lv_conn, lv_cc_email_ids);

           UTL_SMTP.DATA(lv_conn,
          'Date: '   || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, gc_dd_month_yyyy_format) || lv_cr ||
          'From: '   || gc_sender || lv_cr ||
          'Subject: '|| lv_subject || lv_cr ||
          'To: '     || lv_to_email_ids || lv_cr ||
          'CC: '     || lv_cc_email_ids || lv_cr ||

          'MIME-Version: 1.0'|| lv_cr ||    -- Use MIME mail standard
          'Content-Type: multipart/mixed;'|| lv_cr ||
          ' boundary="-----SECBOUND"'|| lv_cr ||
            lv_cr ||

          '-------SECBOUND'|| lv_cr ||
          'Content-Type: text/plain;'|| lv_cr ||
          ' name="excel.csv"'|| lv_cr ||
          'Content-Transfer_Encoding: 8bit'|| lv_cr ||
          'Content-Disposition: attachment;'|| lv_cr ||
          ' filename="'||pv_file_name||'"'|| lv_cr ||
          lv_cr ||lv_message
          || lv_cr ||   -- Content of attachment
          lv_cr ||

           '-------SECBOUND--' );   


     END IF;


     UTL_SMTP.QUIT(lv_conn);


    pv_rtn := TRUE;

ELSE

    pv_rtn := FALSE;

END IF;
```

---

I am calling the procedure by giving the input as the collection table like

PROCEDURE

```
SP1_Send_letter_ATTACH_WAL(pv_job_id IN job.job_id%TYPE,
                           pv_status IN job_transaction_details.status_id%TYPE,
                           pv_subject IN VARCHAR2,
                           pv_message IN stringtable,
                           pv_file_name IN VARCHAR2,
                           pv_date_time IN DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE,
                           pv_rtn OUT BOOLEAN);
```

I just want to store the data of the variable `pv_message` to the variable `lv_message` which is a clob datatype.

```
lv_message CLOB;
```

HOW TO STORE lv_message := pv_message (i.e the collection datatype to CLOB type). I already tried to typecast using 'to_clob()' function like `lv_message = to_clob(pv_message)` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use in the loop the [UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_smtp.htm#i1004100) procedure instead of creating the whole mail.

I can't test it, but should be something like this:

```
          UTL_SMTP.HELO(lv_conn, lv_smtp_host);
          UTL_SMTP.MAIL(lv_conn, gc_sender);
          UTL_SMTP.RCPT(lv_conn, lv_to_email_ids);
          UTL_SMTP.RCPT(lv_conn, lv_cc_email_ids);

           UTL_SMTP.DATA(lv_conn,
          'Date: '   || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, gc_dd_month_yyyy_format) || lv_cr ||
          'From: '   || gc_sender || lv_cr ||
          'Subject: '|| lv_subject || lv_cr ||
          'To: '     || lv_to_email_ids || lv_cr ||
          'CC: '     || lv_cc_email_ids || lv_cr ||

          'MIME-Version: 1.0'|| lv_cr ||    -- Use MIME mail standard
          'Content-Type: multipart/mixed;'|| lv_cr ||
          ' boundary="-----SECBOUND"'|| lv_cr ||
            lv_cr ||

          '-------SECBOUND'|| lv_cr ||
          'Content-Type: text/plain;'|| lv_cr ||
          ' name="excel.csv"'|| lv_cr ||
          'Content-Transfer_Encoding: 8bit'|| lv_cr ||
          'Content-Disposition: attachment;'|| lv_cr ||
          ' filename="'||pv_file_name||'"'|| lv_cr ||
          lv_cr;

 -- this is the importent part (other parts were taken from the question and were just moved out of the loop)
      FOR lv_idx in 1..lv_message_tab.COUNT
       LOOP

         UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(lv_conn, lv_message_tab(lv_idx));
       END LOOP;

     UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(lv_conn,lv_cr ||   -- Content of attachment
          lv_cr ||'-------SECBOUND--' );
```

There used to be a package called `DEMO_MAIL` on OTN but I can't find it...
If you could find it, it's very usefull.

Comment: The format of the mail should not be changed and since the size of the variable which stores the data lv_message is 32767 (since it is the max size of the varchar data type).I am not getting mail if i change the data type to CLOB.so is there any way to get it by using clob

Comment: Please note in the above procedure there are two blocks in the above procedure, if the data is below 30000 bytes it is sent as a single mail.

Comment: @user2294897, I'm not sure that I understand you right. All the procedures in the `UTL_SMTP` are restricted to the 32767 length. So if you want to send a mail with a message bigger than that, you must iterate and use `utl_smtp.write_data` to append more data. In my answer I used your code so I stayed with the `lv_message_tab` but of course you can hold it all in a clob and use [DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_lob.htm#i999349) to iterate on the clob

Comment: I all need is to send the text file greater than 4 mb size (obviously it will greater than varchar2(32767) so i am using clob data type for lv_message instead of varchar) using clob in a single mail,without dividing the files in to many (iterating)

Comment: @user2294897,OK then hold the file content in the CLOB, add all the headers and stuff and then when coming to add the CLOB content - loop on chunks of 32767 (use `dbms_lob.substr`) and add them with `utl_smtp.write_data`. this will create a mail with one file (in whatever size you want)

Comment: Thank you very much A.B.Cade .. It was very help full